# Pivot data Frame example

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Question has been aksed many times, but seems i still not able to used pivot and merge

here my table

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {'year': [2023, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014],
    'cumul': [0.0, 77.0, 100.0, -200.0, 114.0, -11.0, -27.0, 89.0, 195.0, -18.0],
    'evolution': [14.4, -10.3, 28.0, -8.1, 27.5, -10.5, 8.8, 7.5, 10.0, 1.1],
    'nb': [0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 7, 2],
    'pct': [np.nan, 26.0, 100.0, -100.0, 38.0, -11.0, -27.0, 30.0, 28.0, -9.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I try to pivot it in order to have year in column with one line for cumul value, one for evolution one for nb and one for pct
I am still misunderstanding how to use melt and pivot functions in pandas.

```
YEAR   CUMUL   EVO
2023    0.0    14.4
2022    77.0   -10.3
```

to convert to

```
       2022   2023
CUMUL   0.0   77.0
EVO     14.4  -10.3
```

Thansk for your help

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use the `pivot` function. Simply do this:

```py
df.set_index('year').T
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'year': [2023, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014],
    'cumul': [0.0, 77.0, 100.0, -200.0, 114.0, -11.0, -27.0, 89.0, 195.0, -18.0],
    'evolution': [14.4, -10.3, 28.0, -8.1, 27.5, -10.5, 8.8, 7.5, 10.0, 1.1],
    'nb': [0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 7, 2],
    'pct': [np.nan, 26.0, 100.0, -100.0, 38.0, -11.0, -27.0, 30.0, 28.0, -9.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code**

```
df.pivot_table(['cumul', 'evolution'], columns='year', aggfunc='sum')
```

output:

```
year        2014    2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    2021    2022    2023
cumul       -18.0   195.0   89.0    -27.0   -11.0   114.0   -200.0  100.0   77.0    0.0
evolution   1.1     10.0    7.5     8.8     -10.5   27.5    -8.1    28.0    -10.3   14.4
```

**pivot_table Tip**

since 2022 and 2023 are `df` data, you should put the year column, which is the column to which 2022 and 2023 belong, to the `index` or `columns` argument of the `pivot_table` function. Since evol and cumul are column names in `df`, they must be put in the `values` argument of the `pivot_table` function.